# How to use startx as non root?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, xorg

When I log into some user `xyz` and start my desktop environment with `startx` I am logged in as `root`.

`whoami` prints `root`. `echo $HOME` however outputs `/home/xyz`.

How do I get `startx` to take the user I'm starting it from instead of `root`?

Comment: Try to `rm ~/.Xauthority` before using `startx` as non-root user.

Comment: @harrymc did not work. I have another `.Xauthority` file under `/root/` though, should I delete it as well?

Comment: I just tried removing both but its still not working.